# PropertyChangedEventHandler Ready to Work

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, mvvm

I initially had an async MVVM pattern; in debugging I've stripped it now down to only the following - synchronous - code:

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="{Binding Path=bText, FallbackValue=Initial}" Tapped="onTap"/>
</Grid>
```

C#

```
public partial class VPage : Page
{
    public ViewModel    viewModel;

    public VPage()
    {
        DataContext = viewModel = new ViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) { viewModel.onNavigatedTo(); }
    private void onTap(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs eventArgs) { viewModel.onTap(); }
}


public class viewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private String  _bText;
    public String   bText { get { return _bText; } set { _bText = value; DB.major("ViewModel: bText=" + _bText); NotifyPropertyChanged("bText"); } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged == null)
            writeln("Null handler!");
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }

    public void onNavigatedTo() { bText = "Updated via onNavigatedTo"; }

    private int count = 0;
    public void onTap() { bText = "Updated via onTap " + count++.ToString(); }
}
```

That's the entire code base now - I've eliminated all of the Model and Async code to aid in debugging.

When initiated the Page constructor runs and completes.

Subsequently, VPage.OnNavigatedTo gets called, and invokes ViewModel.onNavigatedTo();

On the call to OnNavigatedTo, the writeln triggers, indicating that the handler is null, suggesting that the component initialization hasn't finished in some way.  Subsequently - ie onTap - all works fine and the handler is in place.  Interestingly, the field is updated to "Updated via onNavigatedTo" even though the null handler writeln triggered.

When I had the full Async pattern in place I thought that it was a threading issue but now it's obvious that it's something much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you've given the UI enough time to register its handlers. A quick fix is to yield. Try this:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // This forces the rest of your code to enqueue after UI is done.
    await Task.Yield(); 

    viewModel.populate();
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

The bindings will not activate until your page is in the visual tree. They may or may not retrieve the value first, but they'll subscribe to `PropertyChanged` later.

If you want to ensure that all bindings are in place, then don't subscribe to `OnNavigatedTo`, but use `Loaded` instead.

```
public partial class VPage : Page
{
    public ViewModel viewModel;

    public VPage()
    {
        DataContext = viewModel = new ViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        viewModel.onNavigatedTo();
    }

    private void onTap(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs eventArgs) { viewModel.onTap(); }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this - I tried it in two places [ OnNavigatedTo() and in onComplete() ], but no joy.  Same behavior.  I agree with yr diagnosis though; I'm coming back before the UI is done setting things up.

Comment: Another thought: I'm not convinced it's a race condition - the model thread that gets the text does a remote data access, which takes a relative eternity.  Something seems blocked somewhere.

Comment: Edited the question to add more data after your comment; your comment is still relevant and appreciated.

Comment: you may need to include more to help you out. What does the xaml binding look like? What does the populate/fillText method look like?

Comment: I've greatly simplified the code, to the point of eliminating all of the Model and all of the Async, so as to narrow the field of review.  Full code now posted.